# How to check LWUITList Contains  Values?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have created LWUIT Tabs ,when the user clicks on any tab, I want to execute some logic,the logic **output will be some list of items**,but the problem is when the user clicks on the tab again. My tab related logic is executing continously. I want to stop that,for that I want to place if condition, that should check my list contains values or not,can any one what should be the method I need to use?

Comment: what event do you use to fill the list? I hope not relayout

Comment: Hi,i have displayed my List(list with image)by referring the example http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html  (Check List with Image in this url)

Comment: But issue is with switching between tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myList.getModel().getSize() > 0
```